# Eclipse cannot find java.rmi.Remote class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, rmi, classnotfoundexception

This is a bit weird.

Using the newest Eclipse Juno release, I'm trying to connect to a .NET web service.
Through the build-in wizard I have connected to the WSDL and it generated a java package in my project containing java source files.

However in one of them, I get the error `java.rmi.Remote cannot be resolved to a type`

Example:
The wizard generated the following line for me:

```
public java.rmi.Remote getPort(Class serviceEndpointInterface) throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException {
    //a bunch of code here...

    return _stub;
}
```

Whenever I try to `import java.rmi.Remote;`, I get the following error:

`The import java.rmi.Remote cannot be resolved`

I am using Java v1.6.

Oh, and I am developing an android app.

Comment: I am not sure why I got a downvote for this one. If my question is not clear enough, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could figure out Java.rmi unfortunately does not come with Android and therefore it's not possible to use it.

EDIT:
It may be possible to pack all rmi classes into a jar file and use this jar file within your application. This was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321906/how-to-find-the-jar-of-java-rmi-package)