# Call a method from web app to android app

Tags: android, web-services, api

Is it possible to call a method / API / web service from a web application to an android application, something like android app become web service provider and the web app become web service client,

I would like to refresh data on an android app by clicking on a button on a web application,

Comment: Maybe RMI ([http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321906/how-to-find-the-jar-of-java-rmi-package]) is what you are searching for.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321906/how-to-find-the-jar-of-java-rmi-package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like Google Cloud Messaging - http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html
would probably be your best choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use I-Jetty in your app and make your app as the web server.. use the source code and run the server from a android service. More detail can be found at following link:

https://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/