# Is RiTa framework supporting Android?

Tags: android, dictionary, jar, wordnet

I'm a English learner,and now I'm using WordNet to make a dictionary APP and you know RiTa is a framework for Wordnet, on the homepage http://rednoise.org/rita/index.html it's saying "now with one API for Java, JavaScript, Node, & Android", I download the jar file rita-1.0.90.jar from http://rednoise.org/rita/download/index.html and test it in Android Studio, and it's not working,the I look up in the source  code in rita.wordnet.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManager.java and find something like java.rmi.Remote and so on,we all know Android does not support java.rmi.Remote. so I'm wondering RiTa really supports Android? if so, where to download? was I downloaded from the wrong page?
Any reply or comments are appreciated
My logcat in Eclipse is like this:

```
    06-14 02:15:44.960: I/dalvikvm(2081): Failed resolving    Lrita/wordnet/jwnl/dictionary/file_manager/FileManager; interface 1431 'Ljava/rmi/Remote;'
    06-14 02:15:44.960: W/dalvikvm(2081): Link of class 'Lrita/wordnet/jwnl/dictionary/file_manager/FileManager;' failed
    06-14 02:15:44.970: I/dalvikvm(2081): Failed resolving Lrita/wordnet/jwnl/dictionary/file_manager/FileManager; interface 1431 'Ljava/rmi/Remote;'
    06-14 02:15:44.970: W/dalvikvm(2081): Link of class 'Lrita/wordnet/jwnl/dictionary/file_manager/FileManager;' failed
    06-14 02:15:44.970: W/dalvikvm(2081): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lrita/wordnet/jwnl/dictionary/file_manager/FileManager;)
    ...... They are all like these
```

Answer (score 0):

Android does not permit the attempt to load java.* classes other than those that ship with the OS unless passed a special flag to dx.

But it should be possible to pack all rmi classes into a jar file as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321906/how-to-find-the-jar-of-java-rmi-package).

You were downloading from the right page. FYI this is the link to the latest [RiTa.jar](http://rednoise.org/rita/download/rita-latest.jar) and also a quickstart tutorial for using RiTa in [Android studio](https://github.com/dhowe/RiTa/blob/master/README.android.md#with-android-studio).